# Spark not starting on remote instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, ssh

I started a Spark instance remotely with:

```
./spark-ec2 --key-pair=octavianKey4 --identity-file=octavianKey4.pem --region=eu-west-1 --zone=eu-west-1c launch my-instance-name --resume
```

Then, I made sure I can have TCP access at port `7077` and I tried to connect to it with:

```
spark-shell --master spark://my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7077
```

When I do this, I get:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
16/11/11 20:09:52 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/11 20:09:53 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/52.210.171.38:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/52.210.171.38:7077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:628)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        ... 1 more
16/11/11 20:10:12 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/52.210.171.38:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/52.210.171.38:7077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:628)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        ... 1 more
16/11/11 20:10:32 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/52.210.171.38:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/52.210.171.38:7077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:628)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        ... 1 more
16/11/11 20:10:52 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
16/11/11 20:10:52 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
16/11/11 20:10:52 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
16/11/11 20:10:53 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:528)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2309)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:843)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:835)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:835)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:101)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
  at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:528)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2309)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:843)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:835)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:835)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:101)
  ... 47 elided
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

So, this seems quite contradictory:

1.Some exceptions are thrown, saying that I'm unable to connect.

2.Despite that, the spark shell does start.

3.However, in the shell I can not use normal Spark variables and methods like `sc`

So, what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

1) try `netstat -at | grep 7077` and check master is running on same host

2) go to spark UI default port 8080 and check the --master given is same

Comment: Well, I'm running aws on a different machine, in the cloud, so the master will not be running on the same host

Comment: check firewall is bocking the connection to spark master

Comment: No, it's not that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any evidence that the master were actually running properly: most likely it were not.

Try running

```
   telnet my-instance-name.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 7077
```

from one of your machines. You might also look at the spark logs on that server - to see why the `master` failed to start properly